# Comparing files, path to check filenames, filesize, and checksum md5 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, checksum, filesize

I would like to compare files in a directory that has its path, filename, filesize, and md5 checksum.  I got three functions that works fine for filename, filesize and md5 checksum when I checked them independently.  I think the problem is how I set up another function to process a dictionary with items of a csv files.  Here is the csv files to compare with.

```
|Path|Filename|File Size|Hash
|/var/tmp/test|test1.txt|257|2e6041635f72233f4cdf6fbfb0a8288e
|/var/tmp/test|text2.txt|68|d3428d5910f54270d62ff57ccd5ff52c
|/var/tmp/test|text3.txt|58|42e8b3cba5320e07745110b8b193f534
|/var/tmp/test|text4.xml|128|4acc96e6e8b9006722408e15e555d2c2
|/var/tmp/test|text5.csv|214|a7071c13195d8485b2fb4a68503cbd7a
```

I have tried to modify the md5, filename, filesize and how its looping through the directory but seems to have issues.

```
def csv_checksum(files, path):
    # Get column with delimiter
    csv.register_dialect('myDialect', delimiter = '|')

    csvDics = {}
    # Open file, read them, and output csv formatted
    with open(files, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='myDialect')
        for row in reader:
            if reader.line_num == 1:
                continue
            csvDic = {
                    'Directory': row[1],
                    'Filename': row[2],
                    'File Size': row[3],
                    'Hash': row[4]
            }
            csvDics.update(csvDic) 
            print(csvDics)
            comp_original(csvDics, path)

def comp_original(dic, path):
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        for files in filenames:
            if (dic.get('Directory') == path
                    and dic.get('Filename') == get_filename(files)
                    and dic.get('File Size') == get_filesize(files)
                    and dic.get('Hash') == get_md5(files)):
                print("All files matches")
                return True

def get_filename(fname):
    filename = os.path.basename(fname)
    return filename

def get_filesize(fname):
    stat_info = os.stat(fname)
    file_size = stat_info.st_size
    return file_size

def get_md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
            get_hash = hash_md5.hexdigest()
            return get_hash
```

For filename it goes through the loop but prints out 3 are not matching as `No matches` and one as `All files matches` which all should matched.  Then for both filesize and get_md5, I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text3.txt'`

For filename issue:

```
{'Directory': '/var/tmp/test', 'File Size': '257', 'Hash': '2e6041635f72233f4cdf6fbfb0a8288e', 'Filename': 'test1.txt'}
{'Directory': '/var/tmp/test', 'File Size': '68', 'Hash': 'd3428d5910f54270d62ff57ccd5ff52c', 'Filename': 'text2.txt'}
{'Directory': '/var/tmp/test', 'File Size': '58', 'Hash': '42e8b3cba5320e07745110b8b193f534', 'Filename': 'text3.txt'}
{'Directory': '/var/tmp/test', 'File Size': '128', 'Hash': '4acc96e6e8b9006722408e15e555d2c2', 'Filename': 'text4.xml'}
{'Directory': '/var/tmp/test', 'File Size': '214', 'Hash': 'a7071c13195d8485b2fb4a68503cbd7a', 'Filename': 'text5.csv'}
No matches
No matches
No matches
All files matches
```

For file size:

```
  File "./create_manifest.py", line 44, in csv_checksum
    comp_baseline_manifest(csvDics, path)
  File "./create_manifest.py", line 88, in comp_baseline_manifest
    and dic.get('File Size') == get_filesize(files)):
  File "./create_manifest.py", line 100, in get_filesize
    stat_info = os.stat(fname)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text3.txt'
```

For md5 error:

```
    comp_baseline_manifest(csvDics, path)
  File "./create_manifest.py", line 89, in comp_baseline_manifest
    and dic.get('Hash') == get_md5(files)):
  File "./create_manifest.py", line 107, in get_md5
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text3.txt'
```

Comment: Without looking in detail, maybe the path of `file.txt` is wrong?  You might add a diagnostic print showing what is being passed to the functions for filesize and md5.

Comment: Ok sorry i miss typed that part, is actually text3.txt that complains and if I check that file its md5sum in the terminal as md5sum text3.txt is the same as the csv file and its in the right directory too. For the file size, if I go to the terminal as ls -lh text3.txt i get the same size as 58 I just did print on file size and md5 and don't get anything, added more details of the output errors for all filename, filesize, and md5 issues.

Comment: you should join directory with filename and use full path when you check file size and md5

Comment: @furas ok I run it as ```and dic.get('File Size') == get_filesize(os.path.join(path, files)) and and dic.get('Hash') == get_md5(os.path.join(path, files))):```  and I get the following:  ``` No matches
No matches
No matches
214
No matches
No matches```

Comment: maybe you shouldn't write `No mathes` for every checked file in `for`-loop but you should write it only once after you end `for` loop.

Comment: oh I see, you got an example how I should spin this loop in that comp_original(dic, path)? below @lenik suggestion is interesting which I also tried it.  What is your input for that ```for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    for files in filenames:
        if (dic.get('Directory') == path
                and dic.get('Filename') == get_filename(files)
                and dic.get('File Size') == get_filesize(files)
                and dic.get('Hash') == get_md5(files)):
```

you should have used :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        file_name = os.path.join( root, f )   # <<--- this is important
        if (dic.get('Directory') == path      # `root` here, not `path` ??
                and dic.get('Filename') == get_filename(file_name)
                and dic.get('File Size') == get_filesize(file_name)
                and dic.get('Hash') == get_md5(file_name)):
```

Comment: Thank you @Ienik it takes that path for sure, but the results shows `No matches` and i see i only get one file size output ```No matches: /var/tmp/test/text3.txt
No matches: /var/tmp/test/text4.xml
No matches: /var/tmp/test/test1.txt
All files matches: /var/tmp/test/text5.csv
``` All should say ```All files matches``` since all files are the same in that directory folder

Comment: i don't have your files, so I cannot check myself. it might be a good idea to print explicitly the data you read from the .csv and the data you get from the actual files (size, md5, etc) and see if there's any difference.

Comment: yeah I am doing that and seems like the output in the csv is odd and not sure if sorting that dic is the right way but not sure how I can get this dictionary to work.  I pasted the above results and here is the output without sorting:  ```{'Hash': 'a7071c13195d8485b2fb4a68503cbd7a', 'Filename': 'text5.csv', 'File Size': '214', 'Directory': '/var/tmp/test'}``` it outputs one file only so thats the prob. Not sure how to fix it, I tried to put the ```comp_original(csvDics, path)``` inside the for loop of that ```csv_checksum(files, path)``` function where the dictionary ends but no luck.

Comment: yeah it might an issue how I am looping those messages for no matching, as furas mentioned above.  All files are the same as describe above in the csv file, i already checked and the output looks fine too for the csv file.